# Property does not exist on type (Union type)

Tags: typescript

I am using a type which is one of several interfaces.
When using this in Vue, it says the property does not exist.

```
export interface Link {
  to: string
  text?: string;
}
export interface Text {
  text: string;
}
export interface Html {
  html: string
}
export type DataItem = Text | Link | Html;
```

I'm looping over data items in Vue, but if I try to access a property, it gives an error:

```
 <template
     v-for="(dataItem, index) in item.data" :key="index"
 >

   <p if="dataItem?.text" :class="itemClasses">
         {{ dataItem.text }}
   </p>
```

The error says `Property 'text' does not exist on type 'DataItem'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is not able to infer the type of `dataItem` based on the union type alone(it can be `Text`, `Link`, or `Html`). In this case, you need to perform a type check on `dataItem` to determine its type before accessing its properties:

```
<template v-for="(dataItem, index) in item.data" :key="index">
  <p v-if="('text' in dataItem)" :class="itemClasses">
    {{ (dataItem as Text).text }}
  </p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the variable but I don't think you can do it in the template.
That's because in the Html interface that property doesn't exists and you are making a union (so only common properties are valid).

if you'd be in a .ts file you could access the property like this

```
dataItem.text as Text or dataItem.text as Link
```

The quickest fix you can make is to add an optional property `text` in the Html interface so it will be added also in the union type